# Saving a TObject to a File

Tags: delphi, object, save, delphi-7

How can one save an Object, in its current state, to a file? So that it can immediately be read and restored with all its variables.

Comment: Wikipedia says: "The set of values of the attributes of a particular object is called its state." Delphi actually has no built-in mechanism to save the full object state regardless of visibility, only published properties are supported. RTTI should be extended to optionally include all fields IMHO.

Comment: Is this situation updated?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is called object persistance. This [article](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/comps5.htm) might help, and there are many others if you google for "delphi persisting objects".

Comment: Probably the man used Google which pointed him to Stackoverflow. "Ask Google" is not a real answer. Francois answer's instead is a REAL 
(and useful) answer.

Comment: Nice (and obvious) solution, but its practicality is limited. The OP asked to save an object. Your solution will not work for TObject.

Answer (score 3):

If you descend your object from TComponent, you can use some built-in functionality to stream the object to a file. I think this only works well for simple objects.

Some sample code to get you started:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type
  TMyClass = class(TComponent)
  private
    FMyInteger: integer;
    FMyBool: boolean;
    FMyString: string;
  public
    procedure ToFile(AFileName: string);
  published
    property MyInteger: integer read FMyInteger write FMyInteger;
    property MyString: string read FMyString write FMyString;
    property MyBool: boolean read FMyBool write FMyBool;
  end;

implementation

{ TMyClass }

procedure TMyClass.ToFile(AFileName: string);
var
  MyStream: TFileStream;
begin
  MyStream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName);
  try
    Mystream.WriteComponent(Self);
  finally
    MyStream.Free;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Nice (and obvious) solution, but its practicality is limited. The OP asked to save an object.

Answer (score 3):

As already stated, the easiest way is to use a **Stream** and its **WriteComponent** and **ReadComponent** methods.
But **be aware** that :
- it works **for  descendants of TComponent**, not plain TObject;
- only **for the published properties** (those saved in a dfm), not the public ones nor (a fortiori) the privwte ones;
- you have to **pay a special attention for the Name property** when restoring the component.

You may find some code you could use in these SO answers: [Replace visual component at runtime in Delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/120858/replace-visual-component-at-runtime-in-delphi-win32/122915#122915), [Duplicating components at Run-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239002/duplicating-components-at-run-time/239321#239321)

Comment: Nice (and obvious) solution, but its practicality is limited. The OP asked to save an object.

Answer (score 2):

There's also a roll-your-own [XML method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396550/delphi-object-persistence-what-is-the-best-way) here on S.O.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1. You can use JVCL TJvAppXMLFileStorage (see code below). But JVCL is huge!! You have to consider twice if you want or not, to drag such a huge dependency after you, your whole life.

Solution 2. Save your object to a binary file (my preferred solution). Believe me, it is not that hard.
Use the ccStreamMem.pas, or even better the ccStreamBuff.pas (buffered writing) in my [LightSaber Core library](https://github.com/GabrielOnDelphi?tab=repositories).
You have some code examples on how to do it, in [Delphi in all its glory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZFRZQSM) book.
PS: LightSaber is a lightweight alternative to JVCL.

Here is an example of how to save a record to a binary file. The operation is identical for TObject!

```
// Supposing you have a record (could be also an object) called RAnimationParams that you want to save to disk:

INTERFACE

USES
  System.SysUtils, Vcl.Graphics, ccStreamBuff;

TYPE
  TFrameDelayType = (fdAuto, fdUser);

  RAnimationParams = record
    Color         : TColor;          
    DelayType     : TFrameDelayType;
    procedure WriteToStream (IOStream: TCubicBuffStream);
    procedure ReadFromStream(IOStream: TCubicBuffStream);
  end;

IMPLEMENTATION

procedure RAnimationParams.WriteToStream(IOStream: TCubicBuffStream);
begin
 IOStream.WriteByte    (Ord(DelayType));
 IOStream.WriteInteger (Color);
 IOStream.WritePadding (32);
end;

procedure RAnimationParams.ReadFromStream(IOStream: TCubicBuffStream);
begin
 DelayType    := TFrameDelayType(IOStream.ReadByte);
 Color        := IOStream.ReadInteger;
 IOStream.ReadPadding (32);
end;
```

The padding at the end allows you to change your record/object structure later, without changing the format of your binary file.

To actually save the RAnimationParams to disk you just do:

```
MyBinFile:= TCubicBuffStream.CreateRead('C:\Test.bin');
AnimationParams.WriteToStream(MyBinFile);
MyBinFile.Free;
```

Same code when you want to load the RAnimationParams back from Test.bin, but you use CreateWrite instead of CreateRead.

The TCubicBuffStream class has even dedicated functions such as ReadHeader/CreateWrite that allow you to easily add "[file magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number)" and "file version numbers" to your binary files.

See? Not so difficult. And it will work for any object, not only for TComponent.

---

Example for JVCL, but it won't work for TObject but only for persistent derivates:

```
 uses
      JvAppXMLStorage;
    
    var
      Storage: TJvAppXMLFileStorage;
    begin
      Storage := TJvAppXMLFileStorage.Create(nil);
      try
        Storage.WritePersistent('', MyObject);
        Storage.Xml.SaveToFile('S:\TestFiles\Test.xml');
        Storage.Xml.LoadFromFile('S:\TestFiles\Test.xml');
        Storage.ReadPersistent('', MyObject);
      finally
        Storage.Free;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: `E2010 Incompatible types: 'TPersistent' and 'TSomething.TElse<TYetAnother>'`

Answer (score 1):

[There is a good tutorial here](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/reader-writer.htm).  Keep in mind that you have to have RTTI (run time type information) to save an object at run-time using this approach, so it will only capture **published** properties of a class.

Answer (score -1):

You've already gotten some good answers to your question.  Depending on what you're actually doing, it might be desirable to use a pre-built library or component to save objects.  This is an inexpensive and nifty library/component set that makes it trivial to persist and restore objects, and pretty easily (i.e., with a little bit of code) accommodates persisting even unpublished members of an object:
http://www.deepsoftware.ru/rsllib/index.html  Not something that's rocket science, but if you're doing a lot of this sort of thing this component provides a nice framework for it.

Developer Express also includes a general purpose cxPropertiesStore component as part of the ExpressEditors library that comes with some of their components.